# python script to extract logfile entries between two timestamps

Tags: python

I wrote a python script which does the following things 
  ->reads the content in config file and connects to the remote servers one by one.
  ->On each connection it will fetch a log file from the remote server to the local server
    and extract the log entries between two timestamps specified in the config file.
  ->finally a text file containing the different log entries between 2 timestamps from different server logs is generated.

If the number of log files on the remote machines are more, then it is taking lot of time to fetch, process and generate output file.

To reduce this time, i should execute the same extraction logic on the remote server and fetch only the matched log entries to the local system.

How can this be possible?
Could anyone mind to  help me on this please.

Comment: Please add some code so we can see your mechanisms.

Comment: are you already using logrotate?

Comment: It is of 400 lines  ... date format is different in each log file and there are 15 different types of log files with 6 different date formats. So i cant paste that code here.

Comment: no . I am not using logrotate.

Comment: if you're on a linux server and find yourself messing around chopping up huge log files it is certainly worth taking a look at something like logrotate - it is almost zero effort to setup and may give you what you want without having to write anything custom